# Attach new Timer to every Object

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, refresh

I am using WPF and created a `Window` with informations about the computer.
It stores informations like Network connectivity, IP's, Subnet masks, Network devices and other stuff.

To track changes in the system I want to add an timer on an object to refresh itself. I don't want to refresh the hole form because I had `HttpWebRequest`s in it and it will freeze the programm for a few seconds. It should be easier to see changes and to highlight them.

For example:

```
StComputerInf.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "2. Domain: \t\t" + System.Environment.UserDomainName });
```

I want to add here an timer to refresh itself.

And for every `TreeViewItem` in a `TreeView`:

```
public TreeView CreatTVConnection()
    {
        List<CAdapter> LAdapter = new List<CAdapter>();
        List<TreeViewItem> lConnectedDevices = new List<TreeViewItem>();
        List<TreeViewItem> lDisconnectedDevices = new List<TreeViewItem>();
        LAdapter = ReadAdapter();
        TreeView tv_Adapter = new TreeView();
        tv_Adapter.Name = "Adapter";
        tv_Adapter.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
        tv_Adapter.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        TreeViewItem Connected = new TreeViewItem();
        TreeViewItem Disconnected = new TreeViewItem();
        lConnectedDevices = LoadTV(true, LAdapter);
        if (lConnectedDevices.Count > 0)
        {
            Connected.Header = "Connected:";
            Connected.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            Connected.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
            Connected.Name = "Connected";

            foreach (TreeViewItem tvi in lConnectedDevices)
            {
                tvi.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                Connected.Items.Add(tvi);
            }
        }
        ....
```

And is there a way to see if an object have changed? So I can highlight the affected object?

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory to create your objects.
So for the label example you'd use something like
`LabelFactory.Create(any useful parameters here)` and as part of that method you can include a timer etc.

Also, look into using async/await to update your forms as an easier way to update them without freezing the forms. Once you are comfortable with the pattern you should be able to remove the dependency on timers.

Comment: Now i try it with await async. But if i run the `Task.Run(() =>{}` and i want to generate a new lable in it it crashes with "STA Thread needed". It seems he cant handle the `Window.Form` items.

Comment: Any updates to the UI need to be done on the UI thread. Look at control.Invoke for how to do it